# Programmatically remove specific shipping method - WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, cart

I need to remove my UPS shipping methods on the cart and checkout pages after the cart weight surpasses 150lbs. This is along the lines of what I'm thinking...

```
function is_it_over_onefifty($available_methods){

        global $woocommerce;
        if ($woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_weight > 150){
            //diable shipping
            unset( $available_methods['ups'] );
        }
        else{

            //do nothing

        }
        return $available_methods;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_shipping_methods', 'is_it_over_onefifty', 10, 1);
```

Comment: Did you Google this? This is the first result: http://www.bolderelements.net/support/knowledgebase/hide-shipping-method-based-on-weight/

Comment: Ahh wow, can't believe I missed that. Would you happen to know how to get the shipping rate id's? I'm currently searching around for a way to. @cale_b

Answer (score 1):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'define_default_shipping_method', 10, 2 );
   
function define_default_shipping_method( $rates, $package ) {
      
// Only unset rates if free_shipping is available
if ( isset( $rates['free_shipping:8'] ) ) {
     unset( $rates['flat_rate:4'] );
}     
     
return $rates;
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had started with a comment, but it became too large.

Below is some solid *example code* that will get you going where you need to.  Note the idea is taken from here: http://www.bolderelements.net/support/knowledgebase/hide-shipping-method-based-on-weight/

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'hide_shipping_weight_based', 10, 2 );

function hide_shipping_weight_based( $rates, $package ) {
    // if you don't know what the rates are, you can uncomment below to see all the rates that are available
    // var_dump( $rates );

    // Set weight variable
    $cart_weight = 0;
 
    // Shipping rate to be excluded
    $shipping_type = 'ups_';
 
    // Calculate cart's total
    foreach( WC()->cart->cart_contents as $key => $value) {
        $cart_weight += $value['data']->weight * $value['quantity'];
    }
    
    // only if the weight is over 150lbs find / remove specific carrier
    if( $cart_weight > 150 ) {
        // loop through all of the available rates
        foreach( $rates AS $id => $data )  {
            // if the rate id starts with "ups_"
            if ( 0 === stripos( $id, $shipping_type ) ) {
                unset( $rates[ $id ] ); // remove it
            }
        }
    }
 
    return $rates;
}
```

Comment: hey thanks for the help, I'm getting a 'Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'unset' (T_UNSET)'

Comment: So - I have a typo, but per my answer - this is example code - and expects that you have some ability to troubleshoot / diagnose this.  If not, you may be frustrated trying to hack WooCommerce...

Comment: FYI - I fixed the typo above.

Comment: Ah a parenthesis of course haha. Your going to have to move it down to the if statement though, not the foreach. Thank you for the answer though. Unfortunately, the vardump isn't outputting any info but once I get the ID and if this works I'll mark as correct.